# Assembly MIPS TAl instructions

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions

Can someone point me to a list or something containing all the Assembly (MIPS) TAL instructions?

I believe that

```
mul $8, $17, $20
```

Will become

```
mult  $17, $20
mflo  $8
```

But I was unable to find all instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean MIPS Assembler pseudo-opcodes, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Pseudo_instructions) is a list to get you started.  I have no idea what a "TAI" or a "TAL" instruction is supposed to be.

Comment: "True assembly language"